# Subobjects in $B\mathbf{G}$

Tags: category-theory

I'm really confused proving that the subobjects in the category of representations of a fixed group (sets endowed with a right action of $G$ on such sets) are the subrepresentations. How can I prove that given an object $(X, \mu)$ in $BG$ **there is exactly one** insertion $i: (S,\mu_s) \rightarrowtail (X, \mu)$ in every equivalence class, where $(S,\mu_s)$ is a subrepresentation of $(X, \mu)$?

I tried to use orbits but I got nowhere.

*Edit:* (More information about my attempt)

1. Existence) Given an equivalence class, let's pick up an arbitrary monomorphism $u:(A,\phi) \rightarrowtail (X,\mu)$ belonging to it. We want an isomorphism $\theta: (S, \mu_s) \cong (A,\phi)$ such that $ i = u\circ\theta$. My intuition led me to that S is some union of orbits (respect to the action $\mu$) that corresponds bijectively to $Im(u)$, but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: **Hint:** In the definition of whether a morphism $\phi : (Y, \mu_Y) \to (X, \mu_X)$ is a monomorphism, in terms of morphisms $f, g : (T, \mu_T) \to (Y, \mu_Y)$, consider the special case where $(T, \mu_T)$ is $G$ with the action inherited from multiplication in $G$.

Comment: You really denote the category of $G$-sets by $BG$? Try a more general approach (this way you won't attempt to fiddle around with orbits, which is not necessary). In any category of algebras of an algebraic theory, subobjects = subalgebras. This way, you can immediate apply this result to many more situations (modules, linear representations, lie algebras, rings, lattices, $*$-algebras, etc.).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I'm looking for that result.  Has it a specific name? I couldn't find it.